# So Visual Studio officially supports Git now. What does that mean?

Tags: visual-studio, git, version-control, tfs, visual-studio-2012

I just read an extremely interesting [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/01/30/getting-started-with-git-in-visual-studio-and-team-foundation-service.aspx) that apparently as of this past Visual Studio 2012 update, it now has official Git support built in.

My question is, what does that mean exactly? Does this mean that TFS servers can now host Git repositories? Or, does Visual Studio use something like `git-tfs` behind the scenes to use regular TFS repositories with a Git bridge? Or does this apply to TFS servers at all? Also is using Git outside of Visual Studio which is hosted on TFS plain ol' vanilla git, or is it like the git-tfs bridge?

Also, is there any documentation yet about converting a TFS repository to a Git repository with this support?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Visual Studio Online](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/) hosts git repositories and provide integration to TFS work item tracking and builds.  We store this information in a proper git repository - it's not a transparent **[`git-tf`](http://gittf.codeplex.com/)** bridge.  Instead, we store git references and objects, although we store them in a SQL Server (SQL Azure) instead of a traditional on-disk git repository format.  We do this to integrate with the existing TFS manageability and Team Foundation Service scaling.

Team Foundation Server, the on-premises product that resides in your data center, from TFS 2013 supports git repository hosting. Many features arrive on the hosted Visual Studio Online before arriving in the on-premises product.

Similarly, the Visual Studio integration is a proper git client - again, it's not `git-tf`.  It uses the **[libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com)** and **[libgit2sharp](http://libgit2sharp.com)** projects to provide repository access to a local git repository, as well as network access to provide pushing and pulling to any git hosting service that speaks HTTP.  (The SSH transport is not currently supported.)  This means that you can push and pull to Bitbucket or GitHub, for example, you need not talk to Team Foundation Server.

Comment: Seeing you're a Microsoft employee :) Do you know of any documentation yet for converting a TFS repo to a Git repo?

Comment: That's where `git-tf` comes in.  :)

Comment: @Edward Thomson Any quick notes on how to connect VS to Github?

Comment: @Mark - if you download VS client tooling, you can add an existing local repo (with github as the remote) or clone in VS and simply put in the github clone url from their web UI.  There's a new connect icon in the team explorer window that allows you to connect to local & TFS repos.

Comment: @Mark: see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/01/30/getting-started-with-git-in-visual-studio-and-team-foundation-service.aspx - github is just another git url

Comment: One other detailed additional note - although we store metadata (and some cached/processed data) in SQL server, the files themselves are stored in azure blob storage.  But, still a proper git repo (not a bridge).

Comment: The answer (from January) stated that SSH transport is not currently supported.  Is it supported now, and if not, when might it be supported?

Comment: It is not yet supported; we suggest you provide an upvote on the associated Connect bug so that we can prioritize new feature work:  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/785864/git-cannot-be-used-with-ssh-protocol-in-vs2012

Comment: I notice that connect item is "Closed as External" - I upvoted it, but is there a more appropriate Connect item?

Comment: @EdwardThomson how can I push from the vso git repo to another git repo in the post build events hook? Or how do you suggest? I am stuck here please help. Thanks.